# What are React best practices for a child component to retrieve data over web sockets?

Tags: reactjs, websocket

I am somewhat new to React and am attempting to setup a child component that retrieves its own data from a WebSocket connection. This web socket connection is established in the parent `ComponentDidMount` and is passed to the child component via the prop `socket`.

The issue with this is that I must define `getDerivedStateFromProps` to retrieve the data in the child component only when `this.props.socket` is defined for the first time (the connection is established asynchronously in the parent). An alternative is to use `setInterval` to poll for `this.props.socket` to be defined in `componentDidMount`.

Neither of these approaches seems ideal. Is there a way to make the child component wait for the parent to fully establish the connection? What is the optimal way to accomplish this in accordance with best practices?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit weird to put a WebSocket object in a prop since props are used primarily to transfer data.

One way to do it is to keep all the websocket part in the parent, and let the children use it via a state and a callback.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      websocketData: null
    }

    this.websocket = null
    /* ... */
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let wsScheme = window.location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'wss' : 'ws'
    this.webSocket = new WebSocket(sScheme + '://' + window.location.host + url)

    webSocket.onmessage = (event) => {
      const data = /* get received data from event */
      this.setState({websocketData:data})
    }

    webSocket.onClose = () => console.warn('Websocket closed unexpectedly'
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.websocket) {
      this.websocket.close()
    }
  }

  sendToWebsocket(data) {
    if (this.websocket) {
      webSocket.send(data)
    }
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <ChildComponent websocketData={this.state.websocketData} sendToWebsocket={this.sendToWebsocket}/>
    )
  }
}
```